# new Bitmap - Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, opengl, bitmap

I have a problem with new bitmap, it says that parameter is not valid.

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap("..//..//images//brick.jpg");
```

I have folder images in my project which contains `brick.jpg`.
In other examples the same way of using works but here I have a problem.

Do you have any idea what is happening and what can cause this problem ?

I am using a picture dimension type  `2^n`. Picture is `4kb`. 
This is a visual studio project, not a web application.

It is a runtime error.

Solution:

This helped me because it was in  a wrong place 
Console.WriteLine(new System.IO.FileInfo("..//..//images//brick.jpg").FullName);

thanks

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error or is it a runtime exception. In both cases please add the full error message.

Comment: Source "System.Drawing" string
  StackTrace "   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename)\r\n

Comment: What we need here to help you is the type of exception and the Message it contains. And how can you have a stacktrace if it is compile error?

Comment: @bdl thank you, my directory was at wrong place

Comment: I have this exception just by issuing a new Bitmap(width, height) nothing else and the dimensions of the bitmap is very small so it's not something about memory so there's no image loaded from disk, I just need a new instance of a bitmap. .NET 4.8 on a Windows form app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure the image is located in that directory? (Two dirs up from where your exe is running and then in the images dir).    If you're not sure on where to place the file, you can print the path with:

```
Console.WriteLine(new System.IO.FileInfo("..//..//images//brick.jpg").FullName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the current directory when running from within visual studio is, by default, not the path of the executable, but the visual Studio project path. Go to Project properties, Debugging and set the current directory for executing the application correctly.

Be also aware that the Bitmap constructor throws any type of exception for any type of error. The type or message you'll get does not tell you anything about the cause of the error. It could be "file not found" (the most likely here) but also "image is unreadable" or similar Problems.